# Which mule choice expression when using properties?

Tags: properties, mule, expression

I have a Choice flow control node within my flow. I am basing the choice on a property located in a properties file. In the expression, it appears both of the following expressions work:

`<!-- without using the MEL expression -->
<when expression="${smtp.onSuccess.sendEmail}==true">`

`<!-- using the MEL expression -->
<when expression="#[${smtp.onSuccess.sendEmail}==true]">`

Is it acceptable for either method of expression or does best practices dictate that the MEL expression be used at all times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some processors do not require the explicit syntax. But I generally prefer to be explicit and use the full syntax.